# how to capture and replace with regex in data frame column in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to capture and replace by regex in a DataFrame column  which contains a date, i want capture the following date format in the text "YYYY-MM-DD"
it seems my syntax for capturing and replace is correct but some how it doesn't work.

```
lst_date_version = ["2021-10-10 rev. 002", "2021-11-28 rev. 003", "2021-09-27 rev. 008","2021-11-29 rev. 008", "2021-10-16 rev. 003", "2021-10-25 rev. 008","2021-11-03 rev. 003", "2021-04-12 rev. 008", "2021-03-19 rev. 004"]
df_test_date = pd.DataFrame({"Version":lst_date_version})
df_test_date["Version"] = df_test_date["Version"].str.replace(r"(\d{4}-\d{2})-(\d{2})", r"\1", regex=True)
print(df_test_date["Version"])
```

the result seems the day in the date format is remove (2021-10-**10** rev. 002 ==> 2021-10 rev. 002):

```
0    2021-10 rev. 002
1    2021-11 rev. 003
2    2021-09 rev. 008
3    2021-11 rev. 008
4    2021-10 rev. 003
5    2021-10 rev. 008
6    2021-11 rev. 003
7    2021-04 rev. 008
8    2021-03 rev. 004
```

but when i do the following :

```
 df_test_date["Version"] = df_test_date["Version"].str.replace(r"(\d{4}-\d{2})-(\d{2})", r"\0", regex=True)
    print(df_test_date["Version"])
```

the result is :

```
0     rev. 002
1     rev. 003
2     rev. 008
3     rev. 008
4     rev. 003
5     rev. 008
6     rev. 003
7     rev. 008
8     rev. 004
```

in the meantime i find different way (invert the capture) to what i wanted to achieve by this:

```
 df_test_date["Version"] = df_test_date["Version"].str.replace(r"(\srev.+)", r"\0", regex=True))
```

a big thanks for your help in advance :)

PS: adapted the questions based on remarks :)

Comment: What does `r` have to do with your question? Please consider editing your tags in order for us to be more helpful to your problem.

Comment: `no changes to initial list` ... What happened to the _day_ component of the date?  You start off with `YYYY-MM-DD` and somehow end up with just `YYYY-MM`.

Comment: Also, it is not really clear what you want to achieve. What is the expected output?

Answer (score 2):

Your code fails as `(\d{4}-\d{2})-(\d{2})` is never matching.

You could use `str.split` with `n=1`:

```
df_test_date['Version'] = df_test_date['Version'].str.split(n=1).str[1]
```

else, change your regex to `\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s*`:

```
df_test_date['Version'] = df_test_date["Version"].str.replace(r"\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s*",
                                    '', regex=True)
```

Comment: thank you for your reply :)
can you give some details why str.split with n=1: , please ?
i mean the date format in the text "2021-10-10 rev. 002" can patch the regex "(\d{4}-\d{2})-(\d{2})" correct ?

Comment: @Dinesh I assumed here you wanted to extract the "rev. 00x" string. `n=1` limits to 1 split (after the date). But I might be wrong. What do you expect here?

Comment: in fact i wanted the date with following format "YYYY-MM-DD" in the text 
its because in my initial question i forgot to mention (now I've edited) :) sorry for this

Answer (score 1):

I would use `str.extract` here:

```py
df_test_date["Version"] = df_test_date["Version"].str.extract(r'^(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})')
```

If you want to use `str.replace`, then use a pattern which matches the entire input:

```py
df_test_date["Version"] = df_test_date["Version"].str.replace(r'^(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}) rev\. \d+$', r'\1')
```

Comment: That won't work (no match), the regex should be something like `r'^\d{4}-\d{2}\s*(.*)'`

Comment: I strongly suggest you read the actual question before leaving comments like this.

Comment: then I guess I have not understood what is being asked…

Comment: Wait...I see your point...but the output is not consistent with the data being used to populate the data frame.  In the latter case, my answer is correct, in the former, your answer might be right.